# Can't get Instagram API security code

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm testing the `Instagram API` for a client and am using my personal account for testing purposes only.

I registered an Application on [instagr.am/developer/](http://instagr.am/developer/.).  When they asked for my phone number I just gave them a random sequence of numbers as I don't want  them having my number.  Then when I try to continue to *Register a Client* they say I must *You must verify your phone number to create a Client ID.*

I tired editing my `Instagram profile` with my correct phone number but it asks for my security code there again. And I haven't received anything on my mobile. I entered my number with both `00 [country code]` and `+[country code]`

Problem is I gave them the wrong number.  How can I fix this or start from scratch with the correct phone number.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the exact same error, except I didn't gave them the wrong phone number... I've now tried with several numbers and from different operators and still no text message.

EDIT: I just managed to make it work, using this link: http://sms-verification.com/rec/%2B4796667263.php
It gives you access to a norwegian number (+4796667263) and shows you the text messages. After trying with several numbers from every operator in Portugal and still getting no response, I noticed people was using this to verify Instagram, so I tried it as a last resort and it surprisingly worked!

Comment: This was the only solution I found that worked! Thumbs up and thank you!

Comment: Can't believe they haven't fixed this still. Pathetic!

Comment: Shame that it is still not fixed. Is there a place to report?.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error too and I found this answer on another website:

'What Instagram should tell you is that you need to add your country's dialing code. For me in australia I'd enter +61xxxxxxxxxx. In America it would be +1 followed by your phone number. DO NOT ADD SPACES, BE SURE TO ADD THE +'

However, if you have already put your mobile number and you did so incorrectly, like I did, then all you need to do is log into instagram.com/developer from a NEW browser.

I initially was using Google Chrome, and I tried logging out then logging back, refreshing but each time still got the security code check. So I couldn't enter my mobile number in again.

I then tried logging in via Safari and surprisingly it gave me the mobile verification option, so I added my number in correctly this time and within a few seconds got my 'verification code'.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer. The problem is that they don't validate the numbers or give any prompting about include + and country code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Instagram profile and update the phone number there.

Comment: I tried that but it asks for my security code there again.  And I haven't recieved anything on my mobile.  I entered my number with both 00 [country code] and +[country code]